# How to run YugabyteDB with systemd?

Tags: yugabytedb

I'm looking for some production config files to run YugabyteDB with systemd. It should be able to specify ulimits and restart the processes on startup/failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes systemd requires for ulimits to be specified in it's config too, which the config files below also include.

yb-master service:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/yugabyte-master.service
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
Description=yugabyte-master

[Service]
RestartForceExitStatus=SIGPIPE
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/mycompany_env
StartLimitInterval=0
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/opt/misc/yugabyte/bin/yb-master \
--fs_data_dirs=/opt/data/1/yugabyte \
--rpc_bind_addresses=n1.node.gce-us-east1.mycompany:7100 \
--server_broadcast_addresses=n1.node.gce-us-east1.mycompany:7100 \
--webserver_interface=n1.node.gce-us-east1.mycompany \
--webserver_port=7000 \
--use_private_ip=never \
--placement_cloud=gce \
--placement_region=gce-us-east1 \
--placement_zone=us-east1-c \
--callhome_collection_level=low \
--logtostderr '

LimitCORE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=30
WorkingDirectory=/opt/data/1/yugabyte
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=12000
RestartSec=5
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/su -c "mkdir -p /opt/data/1/yugabyte && chown yugabyte:yugabyte /opt/data/1/yugabyte"
PermissionsStartOnly=True
User=yugabyte
TimeoutStopSec=300
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And one for yb-tserver service:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/yugabyte-tserver.service
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
Description=yugabyte-tserver

[Service]
RestartForceExitStatus=SIGPIPE
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/mycompany_env
StartLimitInterval=0
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/opt/misc/yugabyte/bin/yb-tserver \
--tserver_master_addrs=n1.node.gce-us-east1.mycompany:7100,n2.node.gce-us-central1.mycompany:7100,n3.node.gce-us-west1.mycompany:7100 \
--fs_data_dirs=/opt/data/1/yugabyte \
--rpc_bind_addresses=n1.node.gce-us-east1.mycompany:9200 \
--server_broadcast_addresses=n1.node.gce-us-east1.mycompany:9200 \
--webserver_interface=n1.node.gce-us-east1.mycompany \
--webserver_port=9000 \
--cql_proxy_bind_address=0.0.0.0:9042 \
--use_private_ip=never \
--placement_cloud=gce \
--placement_region=gce-us-east1 \
--placement_zone=us-east1-c \
--start_redis_proxy=false \
--use_cassandra_authentication=true \
--max_stale_read_bound_time_ms=60000 \
--logtostderr --placement_uuid=live'

LimitCORE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=30
WorkingDirectory=/opt/data/1/yugabyte
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=12000
RestartSec=5
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/su -c "mkdir -p /opt/data/1/yugabyte && chown yugabyte:yugabyte /opt/data/1/yugabyte"
PermissionsStartOnly=True
User=yugabyte
TimeoutStopSec=300
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 22.04, any attempts to run yb-master as a systemd service end in a segfault:

```
Aug 22 20:41:04 lenovo1 kernel: bash[37425]: segfault at 7ffd39c25f80 ip 00007fa645ce4354 sp 00007ffd39c25f80 error 6 in ld-linux-x86-64.so.2[7fa645cc9000+2a000]
Aug 22 20:41:04 lenovo1 kernel: Code: eb a0 4c 89 e1 89 ef e8 3a 4d fe ff 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 41 54 48 81 ec 10 01 00 00 48 8b 05 c4 de 01 00 <48> 89 3c>
Aug 22 20:41:04 lenovo1 systemd[1]: yb-master.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV 
░░ Subject: Unit process exited 
░░ Defined-By: systemd
```

I will be glad for tips on how to fix it. Intuitively, I feel that the solution should be relatively simple.
p.s. I'm really sorry, I tried to post a comment, but I "must have 50 reputation to comment"...

Comment: Finally figured it out.
https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/18840